# tensorflow c API lib is missing "cc" folder with lot of header files

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I downloaded an official tensorflow c api lib for windows with cpu from https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c.

The file is:

```
libtensorflow-gpu-windows-x86_64-2.5.0.zip
```

But the lib doesn't contains folder "cc" that contains lot of header files used in examples in the github page. (For example: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc)

So I guess that its lib files do not contains compiled code for those missing functions.

I confused, where can I downloaded a tensorflow c api compiled lib that allow me to write code like in the github examples?